# delete Certain number from linked list (recursive)

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, linked-list, bag

hello everyone i'm trying to create a function that delete a Certain number
from all the cells in the linked list that have this number but my deleting function only deleting the first cell that he arrive to the end and then returning to the main
this is my code:

```
struct num* deleteCell(struct num* point, int numdelete)
{
    struct num* tempdelete = point;
    if (point == NULL)  // found the tail and dont found any match to delete
    {
        printf("not found\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (point->number == numdelete)// found one to delete
    { 
        tempdelete = point->pNext;
        free(point);
    }
    else// Just keep going 
    { 
        point->pNext = deleteCell(point->pNext, numdelete);
    }
    return tempdelete;
}
```

(point is the pointer to the first cell ,numdelete is the number that i want to delete )
thanks for helpers!!!!

alon

Comment: Linked lists are not a good container for recursive algorithms. Better use an iterative approach to avoid stack overflow.

Comment: you must iterate to an item that you want to delete.

Comment: @Olaf this is my task i need to do this algorithm in a recursive way

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi how can i do it ?

Comment: When you find the end, you've completed your deletion -- don't print "Not found"

Comment: @mpez0 it is flag for me when i tried to fix the code...

Comment: i dont see you re-linking the list after freeing a node

Comment: For a recursive algorithm, think "what do I do for a single instance?" Here, if it's a delete number, delete the node (link the next node to the previous node) and do the next node recursively. If it's not a delete number, do the next node recursively. If there is no next node, you're done. Take that, and code it. Yes, it is good to start with the end condition check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct num* deleteCell(struct num* point, int numdelete) {
  if (point == NULL) {
     return NULL;
  }

  if (point->number == numdelete) { 
    num* tempdelete = point->pNext;
    free(point);
    return deleteCell(tempdelete, numdelete);
  }

  point->pNext = deleteCell(point->pNext, numdelete);
  return point;
}
```

Comment: yes it is... done =) but 1 more little thing why yo did point->pNext=(to the recursion)?

Comment: In the case where the next node is deleted, pNext needs to be adjusted accordingly